# collocation data from phone calls

Tags: python, nltk, collocation

I have thousands of phone calls on a daily basis converted from speech to text.
I tried generating collocation data using the two options below

OPTION # 1

```
corpus.collocations(200,2)
```

OPTION # 2

```
bigram = nltk.collocations.BigramAssocMeasures()
finder = BigramCollocationFinder.from_words(corpus)
finder.apply_freq_filter(5)
my_bigrams = finder.nbest(bigram.pmi,200)
```

When I use option #1 I seem to be getting good data but the terms seem to be not very meaning full, example I get terms like "good morning", "good afternoon", "american express"...they are important terms but way too common in the phone calls.

option #2 seem to be getting better data..example..it gives me car make and models, names of cities..etc...

I was wondering is somehone has already used both these options and deciding to go either route and if yes what basis.

I do see some data from option1 that might be good...so am thinking of generating data using both the options..

Any thoughts please ?

***editing my question a bit more**
Based on what I have seen so far, I am mostly going to end up getting most of the results  from option 2 and will merge it with some from option 1.
I am wondering if someone can also shed some light on how the two work differently.

Comment: Take a look at tf-idf: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf

Comment: Would it  be possible to share the dataset? Otherwise, it would be hard to know which method is more appropriate for you.

Comment: @alvas I am afraid cannot share...but looking at the link u sent looks like option #2 already takes into consideration tfidf and hence is getting better data. pointwise mutual information. thank you for providing the link.